# Как реализовать динамический массив?

Tags: структуры

Можно ли реализовать список на базе массивов, от которого требуется:

1. Не константный размер (заранее неизвестен, может расширяться).
2. Время вставки было О(1) или около того.

Посмотрел реализацию в Java. Там получается, что вставка работает за O(1) во всех случаях, кроме случая, когда требуется расширение массива (в этот момент из-за копирования получается O(N)), где массив расширяется в 1,5 раза. Требуется же, чтобы работа операции вставки в конец работала **во всех случаях** за константное время.

Comment: Хороший вопрос. Я тоже думал об этом, но решения не нашел. На базе массива, это для доступа по индексу за O(1) ?

Comment: Да.

Comment: То что вы хотите невозможно сделать, если только вы не знаете заранее watermark. Тогда в той же Java можно его указать и тогда вставка всегда будет за O(1).

Comment: Водяной знак? Что за технология?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пошел дождь, планы изменились, я набросал простейшую реализацию. Ее, конечно, еще тестировать надо, но если кому интересно, выкладываю код.

Прошу извинения, он довольно большой, но как поместить код куда нибудь и дать здесь ссылку на него, я не знаю.

```
/*
  avp 2011

  Динамический массив размером до 2^32 элементов.

  По сути структура MMU с динамическим выделением сегментов данных
  и блоков оглавления нижнего уровня. Оглавление всегда 2 уровня.

  Структура 32-разрядного адреса:
  10 бит индекс в корневом блоке оглавления
  10 бит индекс в блоке сегментов памяти
  12 бит индекс элемента в сегменте данных

  Корневой блок, нулевой блок сегментов и нулевой сегмент создаются 
  сразу при создании динамического массива.

  struct dyna *dyna_init (int elem_size);
    Создать массив с нулевым сегментом 4096 элементов
    размером elem_size байт каждый.
    Дескриптор (struct dyna) выделяется malloc().

  void dyna_free (struct dyna *dyna);
    Освободить всю память массива и дескриптор.

  void *dyna_get (struct dyna *dyna, unsigned int index);
    Возвращает адрес DynArray[index] или NULL (нет памяти).
    При первом обращении память под соответствующий сегмент данных 
    выделяется автоматически.
    Массив в середине может содержать 'дыры' (аналогично файлу в Unix).

  void *dyna_segment (struct dyna *dyna, unsigned int index);
    Возвращает адрес начала сегментв данных размером 4096 элементов
    динамического массива, содержащий элемент с индексом index.
    Если сегмента нет  (дыра, обращений к эдементам массива, входящих
    в этот сегмент не было), то возвращаем NULL.

    По большому счету, надо использовать posix_memalign() вместо malloc(),
    НО в MinGW ее нет.
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct dyna {
  void         **root;    // адресуем по старшим 10 бит.
  unsigned int maxindex;  // максимальный размещенный индекс.
  int          elem_size; // елемент данных в байтах.
};

#define DEBUG 1

struct dyna *
dyna_init (int elem_size)
{
  struct dyna *dyna = malloc(sizeof(*dyna));
  if (!dyna)
    return NULL; // Тут по хорошему надо exit(), ну и далее тоже.

  if (!(dyna->root = calloc(1024,sizeof(void *))))
    return NULL;  
  if (!(dyna->root[0] = calloc(1024,sizeof(void *))))
    return NULL;

  char **table = dyna->root[0];
  // первый сегмент данных
  if (!(table[0] = calloc(4096,dyna->elem_size=elem_size))) 
    return NULL;

  dyna->maxindex = 4095;
  return dyna;
}

void
dyna_free (struct dyna *dyna)
{
  int  i;
  char **tab;

  for (i = 0; i < 1024; i++) {
    if (tab = dyna->root[i]) {
      int j;
      for (j = 0; j < 1024; j++) {
    if (tab[j])
      free(tab[j]);
      }
      free (tab);
    }
  }
  free(dyna->root);
  free(dyna);
}

void *
dyna_segment (struct dyna *dyna, unsigned int index)
{
  int  rix = (index >> 22) & 0x3ff,
    tix = (index >> 12)  & 0x3ff;
  char **tab;

  if (tab = dyna->root[rix])
    return tab[tix];
  return NULL;
}

void *
dyna_get (struct dyna *dyna, unsigned int index)
{
  int  rix = (index >> 22) & 0x3ff,
    tix = (index >> 12)  & 0x3ff,
    dix = index & 0xfff;
  char **tab;

  if (tab = dyna->root[rix]) {
    if (!tab[tix])
      if (!(tab[tix] = calloc(4096,dyna->elem_size)))
    return NULL; // Беда
    // OK tab[tix] содержит адрес сегмента данных с index.
  } else {  // делаем таблицу сегментов и сегмент данных
    if (!(tab = dyna->root[rix] = calloc(1024, sizeof (void *))))
      return NULL; // Совсем беда
    if (!(tab[tix] = calloc(4096,dyna->elem_size)))
      return NULL; // Опять беда
  }
  // OK tab[tix] содержит адрес сегмента данных с index.
  //  char *dat = tab[tix]; // segment addr
  if (index > dyna->maxindex)
    dyna->maxindex = ((index+4096) & 0xfffff000)-1;
  return tab[tix] + dix * dyna->elem_size;
}

#if DEBUG
main ()
{
  struct dyna *dar;
  int *pi, i, *ps, nn[10];

  dar = dyna_init(sizeof(int));
  if (dar) {
    printf ("root = 0x%x, maxi = %d, esiz = %d\n",
        dar->root, dar->maxindex, dar->elem_size);
  } 
  char **tab = dar->root[0];
  printf ("root[0] = 0x%x, tab[0] = 0x%x, tab[1] = 0x%x, segm[0] = 0x%x\n",
      tab,tab[0],tab[1],dyna_segment(dar,5));
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  printf ("segm[0](0) 0x%x; segm[0](2000) 0x%x; segm[0](4095) 0x%x; segm[1](4096) 0x%x; segm[?](100000) 0x%x\n",
  dyna_segment(dar,0),dyna_segment(dar,2000),dyna_segment(dar,4095),
  dyna_segment(dar,4096),dyna_segment(dar,100000));

  pi = dyna_get(dar,i = 4097);
  printf ("root = 0x%x, maxi = %d, esiz = %d\n",
      dar->root, dar->maxindex, dar->elem_size);
      printf ("tab[0] = 0x%x, tab[1] = 0x%x, segm[1] = 0x%x, pi = 0x%x, *pi = %d\n",
      tab[0], tab[1], ps = dyna_segment(dar,i), pi, *pi);
  for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    ps[i] = i+10;
  printf ("ps = 0x%x\n",ps);
  for (i = 4096; i < 4099; i++) {
    pi = dyna_get(dar,i);
    printf ("i = %d pi = 0x%x *pi = %d\n",i,pi,*pi);
    nn[i-4096] = *pi;
  }
  for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    printf ("nn[%d] = %d ",i,nn[i]);
  putchar('\n');
                                      printf ("segm[0](0) 0x%x; segm[0](2000) 0x%x; segm[0](4095) 0x%x; segm[1](4096) 0x%x; segm[2](8192) 0x%x\n",
      dyna_segment(dar,0),dyna_segment(dar,2000),dyna_segment(dar,4095),
      dyna_segment(dar,4096),dyna_segment(dar,8192));
  dyna_free (dar);
  printf ("End\n");
  exit (0);
}

#endif
```

Результаты того, что я запускал, выглядят вполне разумными. Если кто найдет ошибки, буду признателен.

Comment: dyna_get действительно работает всегда за приемлемое время (т.е. random access и добавление). Я реализовал что-то похожее (переделывая), с нормальной обработкой "бед". Хоть и не на базе массивов...

Answer (score 2):

Это не ответ, а некоторые соображения 'по поводу'.

Итак, допустим требуется: массив может расти 'вперед', новые элементы добавляются в конец, время доступа по индексу O(1), занимаемое массивом пространство непрерывно и при этом расширение массива тоже требует времени O(1).

Если отбросить непрерывность на всем протяжении, то можно представить набор массивов (сегментов нашего виртуального массива). Эти сегменты д.б. достаточно большими (тысячи элементов). Этот список может только расти. При появлении второго и следующих сегментов делаем оглавление. Вначале оглавление это один сегмент (один уровень косвенности).
Каждый элемент оглавления ссылается (по адресу) на первый элемент соответствующего сегмента с элементами массива.

Таким образом оглавление из одного сегмента размером N адресует N*N элементов массива.
Очевидно все адреса вычисляются за O(1). Добавление сегментов памяти в массив тоже O(1).
Дальнейший рост массива приводит к появлению следующих уровней оглавления. Два уровня позволяют адресовать N*N*N элементов массива за три вычисления адреса. При N = 1000 два уровня оглавления адресуют миллиард элементов массива.

Разумеется к элементам такого "массива" не получится обращаться по традиционной записи Arr[i]. Для работы с элементами надо разработать удобный набор функций.

Это, конечно, достаточно общие соображения на скорую руку. Надеюсь, хоть частично угадал, что требовалось.

Comment: <i>Разумеется к элементам такого "массива" не получится обращаться по традиционной записи Arr[i]. Для работы с элементами надо разработать удобный набор функций.</i><p>
Конечно же получится! Иначе зачем перегрузка операторов в С++!? Другой вопрос, что реально это будет хитровывернутая ф-ция GetElementByIndex(), но пользователь ничего не увидит :-)

Comment: Т.е. сначала у нас есть одномерный массив из N эл-в, когда добавляется 1000ый эл-т, мы делаем этот массив двумерным? И так далее? Непонятно, как будет происходить этот переход.

Comment: Нет. Мы не строим двумерный массив. Мы строим дерево (1000-ричное).

Листья дерева - это одномерные массивы по 1000 элементов в каждом. В них мы храним данные. Узлы над листьями это дерево содержащее указатели на эти массивы. Каждый узел адресует 1000 массивов с данными. 

Первый узел дерева образуется, когда мы добавляем 1001-й элемент данных. В нем будут 2 указателя. Затем, когда их станет 1001, делаем следующий узел (на 1000 указателей) И ДОБАВЛЯЕМ НОВЫЙ УРОВЕНЬ дерева. В этом узле будут уже указатели не на сегменты данных, а не узлы с адресами. 

И т.д. (место кончается).

Comment: Продолжение. 

На верхнем уровне оглавления у нас всегда один массив размером в 1000 элементов, в котором реально 2 или более указателей вниз. 

В дескрипторе такой структуры (ее адрес вернем при инициализации) достаточно держать: 

1). Указатель на корень (пока у нас только один сегмент с данными блоков оглавления еще нет, следовательно храним там указатель на единственный сегмент с данными). 

2). Количество выделенных сегментов данных.

3). Размер сегмента. (для простоты расчета сделаем сегменты данных и оглавления одинаковыми).

Answer (score 2):

Не знаю почему никто не упомянул [std::deque](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/deque/), в отличие от [std::vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/) при добавлении не делает realloc, соответственно работает быстрее. Если элементом очереди будет < data, next >, то порядок следования становиться не важен...

P.S. мне кажется, что-то похожее описывал [[@avp](/users/232/avp)](/users/232/avp) в своем ответе

Comment: Да, пожалуй, deque выгоднее, чем vector и list :-) Но у vector'а есть очень интересная ф-ция reserve. Которая позволяет заранее программисту выделить определенный объем памяти под будущие элементы.

Comment: Да, deque, видимо то, что нужно (в большинстве случаев, с прагматической точки зрения и на C++). Видимо я понял вопрос @Trash именно как о вопрос об алгоритме реализации на любом процедурном языке (в том числе на ассемблере), обладающим возможностью динамического выделения памяти. О непрерывности 'массива' я говорил, имея в виду эффективность чтения-записи (файлы, сеть).

Comment: Честно мне кажется пользы от reserve особой нет, что сразу потратить время на отведение памяти, что потом. Мне кажется в этом плане deque эффективнее по памяти будет, а если еще и в его настройках покопаться, то можно будет управлять размером выделяемых блоков. На самом деле я не раз встречал людей непонимающих откуда на графике занимаемой памяти образуются пики, а потом спады и во время пиков нагрузка процессор была очень большая. Вектор сначала выделяет новый кусок памяти, потом копирует из старой в новую, и высвобождает старую. Вообщем overhead по памяти периодически случается :)

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно поняла вопрос, то можно использовать "теневое" копирование. Т.е. при "расширении" копировать элементы по шагам (несколько элементов при каждой вставке).
У нас есть 2 массива:

1. Массив длины N, в который добавляются элементы (активный).
2. Массив большей длины, например, 2*N, который находится в стадии заполнения.

Мы будем добавлять элементы в первый массив. Далее, когда он заполнится на 0,75*N (например), начнем копировать по несколько элементов в массив большей длины. Конечно, количество скопированных элементов за один шаг должно быть выбрано таким образом, чтобы  копирование завершилось до переполнения старой структуры структуры :) Возьмём, количество элементов за шаг = 4 (K). Когда элементы меньшего массива полностью скопированы в новый, больший по размеру массив, старый массив удаляется, а новый принимается в качестве активной структуры. Далее (при необходимости) снова создается массив большей длины.

Получится, что доступ к элементам останется O(1), а для добавления элемента понадобится 5 действий (K+1) в худшем случае. А значит, добавление в конец списка будет работать за линейное время всегда. Такая структура, по-моему, удовлетворяет условиям, но будет занимать больше памяти.

Comment: Идея интересная, но памяти многовато уходит. И еще, адреса элементов "плавают". Это, кстати, наблюдается во многих предлагаемых вариантах. В некоторых случаях такое поведение может провоцировать ошибки.

Comment: Это "выровняет" время на добавление, но фактически суммарное время будет такими-же. Т.е. выигрыша-то как такового нет. Так что незачем тогда так мучаться.. а если так хочется low latency, то можно использовать аля-linked list, который будет работать не хуже.

Comment: В общем, да. Но разве можно добиться произвольного доступа за O(1) у связанного списка?

Comment: Позволю заметить, что изначально (в вопросе от @Trash) речь шла о списке НА БАЗЕ МАССИВОВ. Могу предположить, что требуется сохранять, а потом восстанавливать данные между запусками программы. В таком случае для реализации ссылок логично использовать не адреса, а индексы в массиве и использовать read()/write() для целого массива (или его достаточно больших частей).

Comment: "Но разве можно добиться произвольного доступа за O(1) у связанного списка?" - речь о добавлении в него, а не о произвольном доступе к элементам.

Comment: Попробовал и этот метод. При достаточно больших размерах становится ощутимо, что наш динамический массив занимает слишком много. В остальном такой способ, возможно, тоже бы подошел.