# Редкие, экзотические структуры данных и их применение?

Tags: алгоритм, структуры-данных

Все знают про массивы, связные списки, стэки, очереди, хэш таблицы, простые двоичные деревья. Как насчет того чтобы привести хороший, годный пример чего-нибудь более продвинутого вроде [фильтра Блума](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D1%80_%D0%91%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0) или [B-дерева](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE)?

Comment: Фильтры блума повсеместно используются в спеллчекерах, идеи, заложенные в `B` и `B+` деревьях хорошо распространяются на структуры данных для `spatial decomposition` типа `R-trees, R*-trees, PR-trees, ...`. А насколько **годный** пример вы хотите услышать?

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать Чем больше разных структур тем лучше. Заниматься подробным описанием каждой в треде очень долго. Можно еще дать небольшое указание где применяется, как вы сделали с предыдущим двумя. Еще можно вставить картинку/пруфлинк, чтобы было понятнее.

Comment: А вам зачем это?

Comment: @klopp Дабы не упустить возможности создать полезный тред, которого здесь еще нет.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Динамический массив размером до 2^32 элементов с временем вставки O(1).

По сути структура MMU с динамическим выделением сегментов данных
  и блоков оглавления нижнего уровня. Оглавление всегда 2 уровня.

Года полтора назад здесь был вопрос [Как реализовать динамический массив?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/16650) в ходе ответа (скорее спора о возможности операций с такой структурой за время O(1)) появилась такая структура данных. Там и программка есть.

Применение неизвестно.

Comment: Собственно, если я правильно понял, то `dyna_xyz` - это более низкоуровневая вариация на тему `std::deque`.

Comment: Вполне может быть. Никогда не смотрел код std::...

Answer (score 4):

[Красно-черное дерево](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%87%D1%91%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE), применяется в Java-коллекциях (TreeMap, TreeSet)

Comment: Есть у меня смутное подозрение, что автор, не знакомый с `RB-Tree`, не стал бы спрашивать про фильтры Блума :)

Answer (score 4):

самое экзотическое, что я видел - [Дерево ван Эмде Боаса](http://habrahabr.ru/post/125499/)

Comment: На первый взгляд это - всего лишь двухуровневый массив, аналогичный ответу в Как реализовать динамический массив? Причём в ответе - трёхуровневый

Answer (score 1):

Коллега самостоятельно делал buddy allocator - вот это было прикольно, хотя это - и не совсем структура данных. Насколько я помню, чтобы сэкономить память, он на незанятых кусках памяти хранил информацию о соседних занятых. И линковал их в списки. А для фрагментов по 4 и 8 байт он делал ещё как-то по-особенному. Потому что первым способом на них потребовалось бы слишком много накладных расходов :)